# Microsoft.Web.Administration not saving changes to a site's custom log fields collection

Tags: iis, microsoft.web.administration

I'm trying to use the Microsoft.Web.Administration API to configure a site's custom log fields. Here's my code:

```
$serverManager = [Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager]::New()
$config = $serverManager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration()
$sitesSection = $config.GetSection("system.applicationHost/sites")
$siteElement = $sitesSection.GetCollection() | Where-Object { $_.GetAttributeValue('name') -eq $name }

$logFileElement = $siteElement.GetChildElement("logFile")
$customFieldsElement = $logFileElement.GetChildElement("customFields")
$customFieldsCollection = $customFieldsElement.GetCollection()

$logFileElement.SetAttributeValue('Period', 'Hourly')

$addElement = $customFieldsCollection.CreateElement("add")
$addElement["logFieldName"] = "ContosoField"
$addElement["sourceName"] = "ContosoSource"
$addElement["sourceType"] = "ServerVariable"
$customFieldsCollection.Add($addElement)

$serverManager.CommitChanges()
```

However, after calling `CommitChanges`, the applicationHost.config file doesn't show the custom log fields:

```xml
<site name="Clear-CIisCollectiono4adlbez.w4u" id="4">
    <application path="/">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\InetPub\0" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:63001:" />
    </bindings>
    <logFile />
</site>
```

I can add the configuration via the IIS Manager UI.

This is part of an automated test that creates a new site every time the test runs. The first run, the test fails because the custom log field configuration is missing. But on subsequent runs it fails because it thinks the website already has the custom log field in its collection (i.e. the Microsoft.Web.Administration API is somehow caching the collection and applying it to the next site I create).

I've tried using `$serverManager.Sites.LogFile` object directly, and get the same behavior.

After a little bit of research, we discovered that Microsoft.Web.Administration is adding the custom log fields to the first site in applicationHost.config that doesn't have any custom log fields.

I can get `appcmd.exe` to eventually save the changes. It also will change the first website but sometimes it doesn't.

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config -section:system.applicationHost/sites /+"[name='${name}'].logFile.customFields.[logFieldName='ContosoField',sourceName='ContosoSource',sourceType='ServerVariable']" /commit:apphost
```

Calling `CommitChanges` multiple times doesn't work.

Anyone know of any workarounds or fixes for this behavior?

Comment: Did you test this on several machines? All of them showed the same issue?

Comment: Does your problem only occur on iis? Do you have the same problem locally?

Comment: @LexLi It happens on Windows 10, Server 2012 R2, Server 2016, and Server 2019.

Comment: @samwu This is an IIS-only problem. It happens locally, on Windows 10, Server 2012 R2, Server 2016, and Server 2019.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Answer (score 0):

try committing changes for each site individually, immediately after making changes.

Perform operations on the first site
$serverManager.CommitChanges()

Create a new site and perform operations on it
...

Commit changes for the new site
$serverManager.CommitChanges()

Update.

Sorry, must learn to read the question.

Hopefully for security you’ve substituted the actual site with $name. If you have, then apologies.  But, sometimes it’s the simplest things.

Comment: I'm only making changes to a single site, but the MWA API is saving them to another site.

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to documentation the `GetApplicationHostConfiguration()` method "Returns a Configuration object for the default ApplicationHost.config file."

So this part: `automated test that creates a new site every time the test runs` may be cached and the newly added site's configuration is not reflected to `ApplicationHost.config` file. But you can directly use `Sites` collection to modify your site directly :

```
$site = $serverManager.Sites | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $name }

if ($site -ne $null) {
    $logFile = $site.LogFile

    # Here we modify the $logfile
    $logFile.Period = LoggingRolloverPeriod.Hourly
    $logFile.Enabled = $true

    $addElement = $logFile.CustomFields.CreateNewElement("add")
    $addElement["logFieldName"] = "ContosoField"
    $addElement["sourceName"] = "ContosoSource"
    $addElement["sourceType"] = "ServerVariable"

    $serverManager.CommitChanges()

    Write-Host "OK"
} else {
    Write-Host "No such '$name' found."
}
```